# Android Code Optimization Tips

Tags: android

I would like to know whether it is a good practice to write for loop that loops around 400-500 times inside android main thread or should i go for an another thread. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the loop do? If it blocks the UI thread, it should most certainly be in a background thread.

Comment: The loop I'm working with loops around a series of LatLng point and checks for some conditions on each point. Do you think I should be using an AsyncTask for that?

Comment: while ur data is getting processed, do u want any user interface or not? If its heavy process, you should run it in background thread.

Comment: Hey surender, I have only a progress bar in UI and it seems to freeze.  Do you think this looping is freezing it.

Comment: If you are trying to update the progress bar in the loop, it will not work because the loop freezes the UI until control returns to the system. Otherwise, temporarily comment out your loop to test whether that's causing the freeze.

Comment: Thanks Guys, I got the message. Any tips on optimization for problems that involve nested looping like (500x150) in terms of UI or performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say the loop is processing several hundred coordinates, it should definitely be an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or a background thread. Even if the user cannot interact with the UI in that period, this will allow you to show a spinner or dialog for that duration. Further, if the UI thread is unresponsive for more than a certain amount of time, the OS considers the app to have crashed, and gives the user the 'This app has stopped responding' dialog box.